# How to use listagg properly with case statements

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I am trying to use listagg but I'm getting the wrong output. Normally, I would use each case statement separately, but then how would I use listagg?

Table A:

```
 JAN     FEB    MAR    APR    Tag
 C                            102
          D            T      100
          D                   101
 C        D      B     T      103
```

Table B:

```
 Name       Tag
 Ally       100
 Ben        101
 Missy      102
 Noah       103
```

Desired Output:

```
 Ally  Dog,Turtle
 Ben   Dog
 Missy Chicken
 Noah  Chicken,Dog,Bird,Turtle
```

My attempted (wrong) code:

```
 select listagg(
   nvl(
     case when a.jan = 'C' then 'Chicken'
          when a.feb = 'D' then 'Dog'
          when a.mar = 'B' then 'Bird'
          when a.apr = 'T' then 'Turtle'
      end,','),'none')
  within group (order by a.tag)
      from a where a.tag = b.tag
```

Comment: How do you get strings like `'Dog'` and `'Turtle'` from the inputs you posted? I see some single-letter strings like `'C'` and `'D'` in the inputs, but how do you know these mean Chicken and Dog, and not Cat and Donkey?

Comment: These are only all the animals we take in :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, which uses multiple self-joins.

- lines #1 - 14 represent your sample data
- `anima` CTE is here to simplify code; better have it in a table (even if it is a CTE) than use `CASE`
- the final result, lines #24 - 34, concatenates animal names

  - `trim` + `regexp_replace` is used to remove superfluous commas

Here you go:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  taba (jan, feb, mar, apr, tag) as
  4    (select 'c' , null, null, null, 102 from dual union all
  5     select null, 'd' , null, 't' , 100 from dual union all
  6     select null, 'd' , null, null, 101 from dual union all
  7     select 'c' , 'd' , 'b' , 't' , 103 from dual
  8    ),
  9  tabb (name, tag) as
 10    (select 'ally' , 100 from dual union all
 11     select 'ben'  , 101 from dual union all
 12     select 'missy', 102 from dual union all
 13     select 'noah' , 103 from dual
 14    ),
 15  --
 16  -- replace animal codes with their names
 17  anima (code, name) as
 18    (select 'c', 'chicken' from dual union all
 19     select 'd', 'dog'     from dual union all
 20     select 'b', 'bird'    from dual union all
 21     select 't', 'turtle'  from dual
 22    )
 23  -- the final result
 24  select b.name,
 25    trim(',' from regexp_replace(n1.name ||','|| n2.name ||','|| n3.name ||','|| n4.name,
 26                                 '( *, *){2,}', ','
 27                                )
 28        ) result
 29  from tabb b join taba a on a.tag = b.tag
 30  left join anima n1 on n1.code = a.jan
 31  left join anima n2 on n2.code = a.feb
 32  left join anima n3 on n3.code = a.mar
 33  left join anima n4 on n4.code = a.apr
 34  order by b.name;

NAME  RESULT
----- ------------------------------
ally  dog,turtle
ben   dog
missy chicken
noah  chicken,dog,bird,turtle

SQL>
```

Comment: Well, if I can't force listagg, this will do :) thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You *could* do it with LISTAGG in a series of 4 UNION statements, each of them selecting person name and one animal so LISTAGG would then group results per persons, having animal names as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the query through unpivoting within a subquery :

```
select b.Name, a.*
  from b
  join
  (
  select tag, listagg( case
                       when val = 'C' then
                        'Chicken'
                       when val = 'D' then
                        'Dog'
                       when val = 'B' then
                        'Bird'
                       when val = 'T' then
                        'Turtle'
                       end,',') within group (order by 1) as animals
    from a
   unpivot ( val for name in (jan as 'JAN', feb as 'FEB', mar as 'MAR', apr as 'APR') )
   group by tag ) a
     on b.tag = a.tag   
  order by a.tag
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c80fd2d9798ac8822d8bcd805172f57)</kbd>

Comment: Oh very nice, never heard of unpivot! Good to know!

Comment: nice to hear @BFF

Answer (score 1):

```
with
-- sample data
taba (jan, feb, mar, apr, tag) as
  (select 'c' , null, null, null, 102 from dual union all
   select null, 'd' , null, 't' , 100 from dual union all
   select null, 'd' , null, null, 101 from dual union all
   select 'c' , 'd' , 'b' , 't' , 103 from dual
  ),
tabb (name, tag) as
  (select 'ally' , 100 from dual union all
   select 'ben'  , 101 from dual union all
   select 'missy', 102 from dual union all
   select 'noah' , 103 from dual
  ),
  tabab as (
   --select a.tag, b.name, nvl(a.jan,'na') as jan, nvl(a.feb,'na') as feb, nvl(a.mar,'na') as mar, nvl(a.apr,'na') as apr
   select 
      a.tag, b.name, 
      decode(a.jan,'b','bird','c','chicken','d','dog','t','turtle',null) as jan,
      decode(a.feb,'b','bird','c','chicken','d','dog','t','turtle',null) as feb,
      decode(a.mar,'b','bird','c','chicken','d','dog','t','turtle',null) as mar,
      decode(a.apr,'b','bird','c','chicken','d','dog','t','turtle',null) as apr
   from taba a   
   join tabb b
     on a.tag = b.tag
  )
  select 
      name,
      listagg(val,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER by decode(mon, 'JAN',1,'FEB',2,'MAR',3,'APR',4,null)) as listval
   from tabab
   unpivot
   (
     val
       for mon in (jan,feb,mar,apr)
   )
   group by name
   order by 1
;
```